# How to convert an array into an ArrayList?

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an array that is initialized like this:

```
Element[] array = {new Element(1), new Element(2), new Element(3)};
```

How do I to convert this array into an `ArrayList` object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `Arrays.asList(array)` to create an `ArrayList` of your array.